# Anyway to backup nginx before recompiling?

Tags: nginx, geoip

I am looking to install the [HttpGeoipModule for NGINX](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoIPModule) but learning I have to recompile the entire thing from source in order to do so. I have a new Media Temple DV 4.0 server and that comes with nginx v 1.3.0 stock and have never had to recompile from source before and a bit nervous to make changes without being able to revert to a previous state in the event something messes up (that and the fact it is affecting a live server so no idea what downtime is).

My plan was to copy all the existing modules used (nginx -V to list them all and copy the modules already compiled). Then rebuild from source with the copied info above and including the ./configure --with-http_geoip_module reference.

Is is possible to backup the existing nginx configuration in the event something goes wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Find out where all the files are kept, first.**

   `whereis nginx`

   *Example Output:* `nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx
   /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz1`
2. **Copy the directories and contained files and sub-directories to a
   backup location.**

   `cp -Rp path/to/nginx path/to/backup`

Comment: Thanks. I am looking through recompiling from source and it seems like it is going to be tougher than I thought because *from source* will place into previously uncreated or unused directories. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a copy of the existing runtime directory  first (e.g. /opt/nginx).